# How can I create a power function with negative exponent in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, pow, exponent

I've seen many ways to develop a power function in Clojure (recursion, using `reduce`, `loop`, etc), but none of them accepts negative exponents...

Can I do this without depending on Java's `Math/pow`?

Comment: You could use the same exact functions you already seen, only when you have a negative exponent, simply return the reciprocal

Comment: Seems pretty possible to me.  Post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a hint of how you could use the regular algorithms:

[image: the hint]